# SQL- Possible one to many join?

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I am writing a SQL query that needs to identify an address with the same name and city with multiple subnames. So as an example, I need to identify situations that are similar to: 100 Main Street in CityA with a subname Lucas Estates and 150 Main Street in CityA with a subname of Valley Estates. Here is what I have so far...

```
SELECT A.NAME ,
       A.CITY ,
       A.SUBNAME
FROM       ADDRESS A
INNER JOIN STREETS B ON A.NAME = B.Name
WHERE A.NAME = B.NAME
  and (    A.CITY = B.LCITY
        or A.CITY = B.RCITY
      )
  and ISNULL( A.SUBNAME , '' ) != '' 
ORDER BY A.SUBNAME
```

So this gives me addresses that match the streets and have a subname. I need to see the addresses and streets that have more than one subname. Does any one have any suggestions?

Comment: `GROUP BY .. HAVING COUNT` - also, don't tag for *competing* SQL implementations; they are different beasts.

Answer (score 0):

If this, "I am writing a SQL query that needs to identify an address with the same name and city with multiple subnames", is what you really want to do, then a self join might be what you want.

```
select a.name, a.city, a.subname
from address a join address b on a.name = b.name
and a.city = b.city
and a.subname <> b.subname
order by 1, 2
```